# How can I add specific fields to a custom post type, outside of what's included in the default supports?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I've made a custom post type and registered it. I need some more fields for this post type, and would like to add 2 more with the specific keys that will load anytime a new post is made (IE like another excerpt field, but it will say Title/position). I'm not sure how to do this, and would like to avoid plugins. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    $labels = array(
      'name'                  => _x('Executive', 'post type general name '),
      'singular'              => _x('Executive', 'post type singular name'),
      'add_new'               => _x('Add new', 'text_domain'),
          'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add Executive', 'text_domain' ),
          'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Staff', 'text_domain' ),
          'archives'              => __( 'Staff Archives', 'text_domain' ),
          'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
          'all_items'             => __( 'All Exectives', 'text_domain' ),
          'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'text_domain' ),
          'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
          'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
          'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
          'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
          'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
          'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
          'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
          'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
          'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
          'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
          'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
          'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
          'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
          'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
      'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
      'menu_name'             => __( 'Executives', 'text_domain' ),    
    );
    $args = array(
      'label'                 => __( 'Executive', 'text_domain' ),
      'description'           => __( 'Executive Team', 'text_domain' ),
      'labels'                => $labels,
      'supports'              => array( 'title', 'author','name','excerpt','thumbnail', ),
      'hierarchical'          => false,
      'public'                => true,
      'show_ui'               => true,
      'show_in_menu'          => true,
      'menu_position'         => 5,
      'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
      'show_in_nav_menus'     => false,
      'can_export'            => true,
      'has_archive'           => true,
      'exclude_from_search'   => false,
      'publicly_queryable'    => true,
      'rewrite'               => false,
      'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type('Executives', $args);
  }

  add_action('init', 'custom_post_executive');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a custom meta box with a callback that will render the HTML. You can read more about it here: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/

I would also recommend looking at the plugin Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) as they make creating meta fields trivial.

```
function wporg_add_custom_box()
{
    $screens = ['post', 'wporg_cpt'];
    foreach ($screens as $screen) {
        add_meta_box(
            'wporg_box_id',           // Unique ID
            'Custom Meta Box Title',  // Box title
            'wporg_custom_box_html',  // Content callback, must be of type callable
            $screen                   // Post type
        );
    }
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'wporg_add_custom_box');

function wporg_custom_box_html($post)
{
    ?>
    <label for="wporg_field">Description for this field</label>
    <select name="wporg_field" id="wporg_field" class="postbox">
        <option value="">Select something...</option>
        <option value="something">Something</option>
        <option value="else">Else</option>
    </select>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: I'm a little new to php so sorry for my ignorance here. It looks like in the first one, you're adding a text field, and the second batch is adding a select field? With that in mind, how does it know which page to these are to be rendered on? Isn't this supposed to go in the functions.php file? The docs make it seem like $screens is where it get's it, but how do I know what the value of $screen is?